# HTML/CSS - styling solution for overscroll of dynamic content (video backgrounds)?

Tags: html, css, video, webflow

I'm looking for a solution to overscroll occurring at the top / bottom of website where a video / constantly changing image is the site content. On a static color someone can simply set the site background to the same color to prevent users from scrolling past the site content. This isn't possible with site content that is constantly changing.

I'm working in Webflow and have an mp4 playing as the hero shot on a white site background. Here is the problem:

**Overscroll:**
[image]

**No overscroll:**
[image]

I considered making the video slightly bigger than the site frame, but the browser cuts off anything that is outside of the viewable canvas. What is the solution here? How can I mitigate overscroll with dynamic site content?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right.

You didn't mention any details of the implementation or code but here is a simple code.

using a **video** element and giving it **position fixed** and **min-width** and **min-height** of **100%**

if this is how you implemented it, just make sure to remove margins from the body, ***simply removing all margins*** is recommended always.

Check the snippet.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myVideoBackground{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" class="myVideoBackground"></video>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas sunt, nobis, veniam ullam obcaecati officia laboriosam porro minima quasi fugiat iste, autem ipsum in doloribus. Neque commodi eos est accusamus.</p>
    <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas sunt, nobis, veniam ullam obcaecati officia laboriosam porro minima quasi fugiat iste, autem ipsum in doloribus. Neque commodi eos est accusamus.</p>
```